# access denied on information_schema.triggers?

Tags: mysql, triggers, user-permissions, information-schema

Just testing some code, trying to save all the triggers in a database then re-create them

```
drop table if exists triggertemp;

create table triggertemp like information_schema.TRIGGERS;

insert into triggertemp (
select * from information_schema.TRIGGERS where TRIGGER_SCHEMA = 'id2target');

delete from information_schema.TRIGGERS where TRIGGER_SCHEMA = 'id2target';

-- and then to re-create them
insert into information_schema.TRIGGERS (select * from triggertemp);
```

But I get Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database information_schema. Now I've granted every privilege on every schema for this user, but still nothing.

have I missed a privilege? Or is this a built in safety and I'm going about things wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html says:

> you can only read the contents of tables, not perform INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations on them.

If you want to preserve the triggers and then restore them you could do this:

```
$ mysqldump --triggers --no-create-db --no-create-info --no-data id2target > triggers.sql

$ mysql id2target < triggers.sql
```

Comment: can that be used to apply just the triggers to the target database after changes to the data? or will it revert the database contents back as well?

Comment: @KellyLarsen, Please read the [documentation on mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) to understand the respective options I show above. I'm not going to retype information that is readily available.

Comment: I apologise. I've just been on the same problem all afternoon and it's making my brain squishy. I'll have a go over it tomorrow. Appreciate the help :)

Comment: Thanks, no apology necessary. I'd also like to apologize if my previous comment sounded grouchy. That was not my intention. It was a long day for me too. But anyway, it's worth your time to read the docs! Lots of good information in there. :-)